# In Grails spock test, how do I mock a custom taglib, called inside a custom taglib?

Tags: unit-testing, grails, spock, grails-2.3

Okay, I have a custom taglib inside a custom taglib like so:

```
def preference = { attrs, body ->

        def sliderTaglib = grailsApplication.mainContext.getBean('com.myCustom.sliderTagLib')
        sliderTaglib.slider.call(attrs, body)

}
```

Since I am using `grailsApplication.mainContext.getBean()` , how do i mock that in my unit test? My test complains:

```
grails Error executing tag No bean named is defined...
```

I've tried various methods to mock it but to no avail. It functions correctly when I run-app though, it's just the test that fails. I'm using grails 2.3.9 and spock. :(

My test looks like this:

```
void "taglib should output a slider"() {
    when:
    def result = applyTemplate("""
        <a:preference class='slider'/>
    """)
    then:
    result == "<div class='slider'></div>"
}
```

Comment: how does your test look like? if you could provide some more details regarding the test, that might help

Comment: I just used the regular `applyTemplate` and matched the result against expected. I'll update it above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can mock the taglib by using

```
@TestMixin(GroovyPageUnitTestMixin)
class MultipleTagLibSpec extends Specification {

    void "test multiple tags"() {
        given:
        mockTagLib(sliderTagLib)

        expect:
        // …
    }
}
```

By the you should must not lookup the `sliderTagLib` bean in the application context. You simple call the taglib by calling the `taglib-namespace`.`taglib-method`.

E.g. the Grails taglibs are in the `g` namespace. Therefore use it like this.

```
def preference = { attrs, body ->
    out << g.link(...)
    // in your case
    yourNamespace.slider(....)
}
```

Comment: I see. I figured, since I can simply call g.message() or other grails standard taglibs in my taglib, theoretically I can just call my custom taglibs the same way... I shall try this first thing in the morning tomorrow. I think it was the first thing I tried, but I hit an error in the test, so I searched a bit on the internet, and ended up with getting the bean.

Comment: Thanks! It works! It just so happens that I didn't use out as in `out << myNamespace.slider` in the preference. :)